# Is there a elegant way to update multiple items in a Immutable List using immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, immutability

I need to update all items of a Javascript Immutable List, using the immutable.js library, without `IF` conditions. Now I'm doing it using an auxiliary list, like the following code:

```
const secondList = [];

firstList.map((item, i) => {
    item.position = i;
    secondList.push(item);
});

firstList = Immutable.List(secondList);
```

Can I optimize this code using an Immutable specific function?

Answer (score 0):

> Immutable data cannot be changed once created

So... I think you got it wrong. Either you should not be using an immutable, either you shouldn't be modifying it there.

If you still wanted to do this, you could use the real way `Array.map` should be used, instead of using it just like `Array.forEach`. The difference is that the map's callback returns the (modified) data and the result of map is an array with that data modified... So we can shorten your code a bit.

```
firstList = Immutable.List(firstList.map((item, i) => {
    item.position = i;
    return item;
}));
```

Comment: Why shouldn't I modify my immutable list? In this case, I'm doing an operation and returning a new List, so the original list isn't modified, keeping the concept of immutable objects, am I wrong?
I've thought maybe the library has a way to do it without loops.

Comment: The quote is coming directly from immutable.js documentation. You cannot directly modify it, but you can modify it's reference, just like you did in your code. You are indeed return a new list, and replace the old list with it. That exactly the same as modifying your immutable directly...